# Spending block reward after subsidy end

Tags: reward-schedule, immature-coins

After block subsidy goes to zero does a miner still have to wait 100 blocks to spend the reward (from the fees)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. We still need to allow time for small-scale block reorganisations. Miners of stale blocks should not collect and spend fees that are needed by ultimately successful miners of the same transactions.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I asked this question because we were debating what would be the minimum amount of UTXOs that can ever be. So I guess 102 utxos?
https://twitter.com/zndtoshi/status/1576966894178865152?s=20&t=o_AXxaDusRgNmlg_q-NwKw

Comment: @zndtoshi It's actually zero, since the coinbase transaction can send the block reward to an OP_RETURN output, which doesn't create a new UTXO.